# fusion table query WHERE ST_INTERSECTS don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-fusion-tables

I have read many questions related to mine and I have tried many solutions but still the code don't work.

When I click on map I have the desired result (name of polygon ) but when I query the table nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1253">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="el">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDZbke25XIzzLt04B93oaJdESKE3lbrgAM&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
        <script>
             function initMap() {                    
               var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
               center: {lat: 38.0010, lng: 23.8743},
               zoom: 5,
               disableDefaultUI: true,
               zoomControl: true
             });
             layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
               map: map,
               heatmap: { enabled: false },
               query: {
                 select: "col2",
                 from: "1Bf6zLV8tWlmdqGAt5lMvVmPZ-b47szjMEjwmJGc9",
                 where: ""
               },
               options: {
                 styleId: 2,
                 templateId: 2
               }
             });
             }
             function getname(latlng){
                 alert(latlng);
                 var queryStr = [];
                 queryStr.push("SELECT name ");
                 queryStr.push(" FROM " + '1Bf6zLV8tWlmdqGAt5lMvVmPZ-b47szjMEjwmJGc9');
                 // set coordinates and tolerance radius
                 queryStr.push(" WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG("+latlng+"), 1))");
                 var sql = encodeURIComponent(queryStr.join(" "));
                 // try complete query here
                 //var sql="SELECT name FROM 1Bf6zLV8tWlmdqGAt5lMvVmPZ-b47szjMEjwmJGc9 WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,CIRCLE(LATLNG(38.0010,23.8743),1))";
                 $.ajax({
                 url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql="+sql+"&key="+"AIzaSyDZbke25XIzzLt04B93oaJdESKE3lbrgAM",
                 dataType: "json"
             }).done(function (response) {
                 document.getElementById("prefecture").value = response.rows[0][0];
             });
             }

        </script>
        <style>
            #map {
                width: 100%;
                height: 350px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <input type="text" Name="prefecture" id="prefecture">
        <input type="button" value="GetName" name="B1" onClick="getname('38.0010,23.8743');">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you query the table?

Comment: Looks like you're passing a single string variable to the query when calling the `getName()` function.